# AngularJS - Unwatching auto bound values within curly braces

Tags: angularjs

Is there a built-in method to AngularJS to remove the automatically created watch on a value inserted into a template via curly braces.

For example:

```
<span>{{someVal}}</span>
```

In my case, **someVal** is never going to be changed after it's loaded the first time. I don't need the watch code listening for changes. I'm trying to speed up a page's performance that has a rather large table - some values the user can edit but most are read-only values.

I'm not setting up a watch manually so I don't have a reference to the deregistration method for each value. Do I need to write a custom directive to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A buddy of mine found this set of directives for this exact purpose.

https://github.com/abourget/abourget-angular

Answer (score 1):

I have recently found a better way of doing it as it's built in the angular:

```
<span>{{::someVal}}</span>
```

More information here: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression

Comment: Yes - that is new as of Angular 1.3, and should be used going forward.